# Scheduling Emails Using PHP + MySQL + Cron

Tags: php, laravel, task-queue

I'm writing a web app in PHP + Laravel + MySQL.

In the system, a user can schedule emails (and other API calls) at arbitrary times (much like how you schedule posts in WordPress). I can use CRON to inspect the database every 5min or so to find emails that should be sent, send them, and update their status.

However, this is a SaaS app. So the amount of emails to be sent at a particular time can grow rapidly. I can create a "lock file" every time the CRON script runs so that only one instance of it is running at a time. The lock file will be deleted after a script finishes execution.

But with potentially large data, I would want a way to process multiple messages simultaneously, potentially using multiple "workers." Is there any existing solution manage such a queue?

Comment: Good question ! Waiting for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! [Task/Message/Job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) queues are what you are looking for! They allow you to  put various tasks in queues from which you can retrieve them and process them, this process can scale horizontally as each worker can pull a task once its finished with the previous one.

You should have the cron maybe every minute/two minutes that just uploads the task and what needs to be done. This will make sure the cron is very quick.

Take a look at [Iron.io](http://www.iron.io/) Here is an extract from the website which gives a nice overview of these kinds of systems:

> An easy-to-use scalable task queue that gives cloud developers a
>   simple way to offload front-end tasks, run scheduled jobs, and process
>   tasks in the background and at scale.

[Gearman](http://gearman.org/) is also a great solution that you can use yourself and is very simple. You can send the message in many different languages and use a different langauge to process it. Say PHP -> C etc...

The [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) will tell you everything you need to know, here is a quick excerpt:

> Message queues provide an asynchronous communications protocol,
>   meaning that the sender and receiver of the message do not need to
>   interact with the message queue at the same time. Messages placed onto
>   the queue are stored until the recipient retrieves them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Another way I can accomplish this is by using a single cron job to fetch pending tasks and then push them to beanstalkd (Laravel supports this). However, is it possible to have have multiple cron jobs simultaneously push pending tasks to the queue? We hit a potential race condition between multiple "cron pullers".

Comment: Yes you can push tasks simultaneously to the queue, the whole benefit of the worker/job system is that each one pulls a certain number of tasks off the queue. Take a look at this diagram: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19263-01/817-6024/images/adm_clientruntime9.gif, you can have as many *consumers* as you want processing tasks. These systems are designed to remove this *race* problem. Each worker does not pull the whole queue at the same time, only a set amount of items such as 1.